# Draw 2D Polyhedra with halfspace

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is possible to help me draw 2D Polyhedra on LaTex please?

[image]

Your help is much appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is straightforward to draw something along these lines but if you try to do it yourself you will see that this is much more fun. Especially since then you won't depend on others.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[fill=gray!60] (0,0) coordinate(p1) --  ++(35:2.5) coordinate(p2)
 -- ++(-45:2.5) coordinate(p3) --
 ++(-120:3.5) coordinate(p4) --  ++(150:3) coordinate(p5);
 \node at (barycentric cs:p1=1,p2=1,p3=1,p4=1,p5=1) {$\mathcal{P}$};
 \foreach \X [count=\Y] in {2,...,6}
 {\ifnum\X=6
   \path (p\Y) -- (p1) coordinate[pos=-0.2](a\Y) coordinate[pos=1.2](a1)
   coordinate[pos=0.5](m1);
   \draw (a\Y) -- (a1);
   \draw[-latex] (m1) -- ($ (m1)!1.2cm!90:(p1) $) node[pos=1.2]{$a_{\Y}$};
  \else
   \path (p\Y) -- (p\X) coordinate[pos=-0.2](a\Y) coordinate[pos=1.2](a\X)
   coordinate[pos=0.5](m\X);
   \draw (a\Y) -- (a\X);
   \draw[-latex] (m\X) -- ($ (m\X)!1.2cm!90:(p\X) $) node[pos=1.2]{$a_{\Y}$};
  \fi}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]